# Spring boot and BACnet4j

Tags: spring, spring-boot, udp, bacnet4j

I'm trying to run BACnet4j with spring boot together.

BACnet4j is implementation of BACnet protocol, in my case it is BACnet IP (UDP communication on port ex.47808).

When I start my BACnet app alone it's working fine. (application is simple BACnet master - providing some objects on network)

When I try to integrate it with spring it's seem that everything starts correctly but BACnet communication doesn't work. (no response on Who-is from other device).

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to troubleshoot the issue is using Wireshark. Start Wireshark on your system, parallel run your Spring app. Make Who-Is request from app and check Wireshark if the request has been dispatched. If it has been dispatched then wait for response from device. You will see the response in Wireshark